# issues with headphones

Tags: music, audio

I have a Lumia 640, which is about a month old. I noticed that my best headphones don't work in days, basically there's no sign that they are even plugged, the sound plays from the speaker.

here's the funny part: when I tried some cheap supermarket earbuds(in ear), and what a miracle, they worked like a charm. the sound was terrible of course, but what do you expect for 5 bucks. So I ordered other earbuds online (original Nokia) and it does not recognize them, same deal as with the headphones and now im pretty dissapointed.

so, some fixes that i've tried:
1) restart
2) soft reset
3) hard reset
4) upgrading to windows 10
5) cleaning the holes

ohh and i almost forgot to mention, the apple iphone earbuds also worked perfectly. i find it wierd that some accessories work and others don't. would anyone have some suggestions please.

Comment: Does the Microsoft Gadgets app recognise your headphone?

Comment: Try the headphones in a computer or other device to see if the headphones are the problem.